# Cannot access nexus in offline mode and the artifact is not downloaded

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus

We are facing an issue with the Maven build. We have setup proxy in Eclipse, got Maven installed, and all the required settings completed. But every time we try to build it we are getting following exception:

> Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.4.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved
>
> Cannot access nexus in offline mode and the artifact org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:jar:1.4.8 has not been downloaded from it before.

We have set all the dependencies. One of the dependencies shows a message:

> Offline / Missing artifact com.xxxxx.xxxx:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT

Why do we get this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Please, post your `pom.xml` and `settings.xml` files, as it's hard to figure out what you've done.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 <servers>
  <server>
   <id>nexus</id>
   <username></username>
   <password></password>
  </server>
 </servers>
 <mirrors>
  <mirror>      <!-- This sends everything else to /public -->
   <id>nexus</id>
   <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
   <url>   http://nexus.**********.com/nexus/content/groups/CLM/ </url>

 </mirrors>
</settings>

Comment: You need to post this as part of your question and use the proper formatting (not as a comment). Also, please attach the actual `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 6):

I've had a similar problem after changing from eclipse to intelliJ.
The message told me, that i was in offline mode like yours and i found a solution:

Go to the general settings

```
-> Build, Execution, Deployment 
-> Build Tools 
-> Maven
```

Here the checkbox "Work offline" was checked.
To fix the problem simply uncheck this box and you're fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).